# How to add additional info to a existent keras NN model in order to improve accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, regression

So, I'll briefly describe the domain of the problem and I state that I am a beginner in neural networks and keras in general so the answer might be trivial for you.
I have a dataset composed by the following rows:

```
v0;v1;v2;v3;err
27;45;35;40;9.421857761389568e-17
42;23;4;10;0.15046260426547653
7;52;45;4;0.004021030533106114
8;13;21;8;3.527736174640165e-05
50;40;3;39;0.2594155190453719
..........
..........
```

I want to predict the errors given the variable values. As you can imagine, this is a fairly easy regression problem (not linear in my case) that I solved with different NN models (I also preprocessed data with normalization for the variables and standardization for the error first). In fact, I trained different models with different dense layers and I found out that the best one gave me an accuracy of 96.5% more or less.

Supposed this is the best result I can achieve with keras NN models (maybe not but it does not matter), I have an additional info about the domain that I want to use to increase the accuracy. In fact, the error value depends in some way also on some relations between the different `v` values. I know that
if `v0<v3 and v1<v3 and v3<v2`, the error is the lowest possible, while if some of these relations are violated, the error increases in some way. 
So, is there a way to let the NN model also learn those relationships and the consequent decreases or increases of the error if violations are absent or present? I read some papers and some stuff online and I found out that maybe I can represent these dependencies with a graph and then put a GNN layer (or layers) in the current NN model to try to improve the final result. This is just an idea, I don't know if this is possible to do and if it is the best thing to do. Any ideas?

Thank you to anyone that can help me, really appreciated!

Comment: You could create new features calculated as the differences between the other features e.g. `new_feat_1 = v3 - v0` etc. This will allow the model to learn that when that value is negative, then the error is lower. Otherwise, and depending on your intuition behind the problem, you can create new binary features e.g. `new_feat_1 = 1 if (v3 - v0) >0 else 0`.

Comment: Oh ok fine, seems reasonable. What do you think about the two approaches you suggested me? What is the preferred one to learn faster and more accurately? Both of them are going to modify the dataset anyway with some artificial features if I understood correctly...

Comment: As I said, it depends on your understanding of the problem. If the error is lower only when `v3>v0` (i.e. the actual difference does not impact the error), then the binary feature should, theoretically, be better. And vice versa. In any case, you could create both and test it. Similarly, you can create higher-level feature combinations e.g. `new_feat = 1 if (v0<v3 and v1<v3 and v3<v2) else 0`.

Comment: the error is the lowest possible if all the relations are not violated, so `if v0<v3 and v1<v3 and v3<v2`. Anyway yes, I will try every strategy and compare the solutions. I was asking that only to know if I should have expected one solution to be better than another while testing all of them. Thank you!